# How can I return any NON-NULL value in an aggregate/GROUP BY query?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I return any NON-NULL value in an aggregate/GROUP BY SQL query in Snowflake?

Along with other information from a table, I want to get an arbitrary value for a user_id attribute that could be null in the data (but still pull in rows where that attribute is null.) How can I get a value for that attribute that will NOT be one of the null values?

I'd like to do this to avoid the more computationally expensive (I assume) MIN/MAX route for the attribute value.

I'd like to do something like
`SELECT user_id, ANY_VALUE(attribute) IGNORE NULLS FROM foo`
but it doesn't seem that IGNORE NULLS is supported like it is for FIRST_VALUE(), for example.

Comment: WHERE attribute IS NOT NULL ?

Comment: Have you tested the performance impact of ANY_VALUE (and it being wrong for purpose) verse MAX. I agree there is a cost, but is it as bad as the concern. Because I don't feel there are other methods with using a JOIN which also is costly.

Comment: @NickW, I edited my question to make it clearer, but I don't want to filter out rows that are not null generally, I just want to return an arbitrary value for a specific field and have that value be not null.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim, fair that MAX might be the best answer, but I wanted to learn if there was a better alternative. (Haven't tested the speed.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to improve performance, I'd follow Simeon's advice to just do `MAX()` — it should be fast.

If you want some SQL syntax to just get the first element that is not null `array_agg()[0]` can get you that — because `array_agg()` ignores nulls:

```sql
with data as ( 
    select 'a' label, $1 i from values (1),(2),(3),(null)
)

select label, array_agg(i)[0]
from data
group by label;
```

But this will probably be slower and fail if there's too many rows involved.

Comment: Sounds like MAX is the best alternative. Thanks Felipe et al!